# Compose.jl output issue

Tags: julia

Ok recently I have been experimenting with Julia's compose.jl and have run into a somewhat confusing problem. I will run the standard code to initialize the package.

```
Pkg.add("Compose")
using Compose
compose(compose(context(), rectangle()), fill("tomato"))
```

And then run that code. Here is my problem: the code executes fine, it's the output that is strange. The typical output for this code would be a red rectangle. The output I get when this code is run is this:

```
Context(BoundingBox(Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),1.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,1.0)),UnitBox{Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing}(nothing,nothing,nothing,nothing,Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0)),Rotation{Point{Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil},Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}}}(0.0,Point{Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil},Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}}(Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.5,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.5))),nothing,ListNode{ComposeNode}(Property{FillPrimitive}([FillPrimitive(AlphaColorValue{RGB{Float64},Float64}(RGB{Float64}(1.0,0.38823529411764707,0.2784313725490196),1.0))]),ListNode{ComposeNode}(Form{RectanglePrimitive{P<:Point{XM<:Measure{S,T},YM<:Measure{S,T}},M1<:Measure{S,T},M2<:Measure{S,T}}}(RectanglePrimitive[RectanglePrimitive{Point{Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil},Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}},Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil},Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}}(Point{Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil},Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}}(Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,0.0)),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),1.0,0.0),Measure{MeasureNil,MeasureNil}(0.0,MeasureNil(),MeasureNil(),0.0,1.0))]),ListNull{ComposeNode}())),0,false,false,false,false,nothing,nothing,0.0)
```

a rather lengthy piece of text that doesn't show the shape... I am wondering if this is an error or if I am just doing something wrong. Does anyone know how to make this output what it should be?

Comment: Where are you running it? In an IJulia notebook or at the REPL?

Comment: This works fine on JuliaBox or from the IJulia notebook.  I suspect you have no backend specified or running.  Lacking a backend, `Compose` shows you the tree in text.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to open an image through REPL would be through [TerminalExtensions.jl](https://github.com/Keno/TerminalExtensions.jl). But generally I believe you have to write the image to a file and then open it. To save the file use this,

```
julia>draw(PNG("test.png", 10inch, 10inch), compose(compose(context(), rectangle()), fill("tomato")))
```